# With Chef, how to execute "resource 1" before "resource 2", conditional on "resource 2" executing?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a Chef cookbook, with multiple recipes, that installs a service. The way chef-client works, it re-converges every 15 minutes (or some other regular interval). Right now the first step of my cookbook is to stop the service, so the service will stop every 15 minutes, but I really want to avoid this. The problem is that the service needs to be stopped for some steps to be executed.

If I only had one or two conditions in my recipes' resources, I could simply do:

```
condition1 = ... # some true/false values
condition2 = ... #

service myservice do
  only_if { condition1 or condition2 }
  action :stop
end

resource1 do
  only_if { condition1 }
end

resource2 do
  only_if { condition2 }
end
```

But as I have a dozen or so conditions, in multiple recipes, it gets inelegant. Is there a way to do what this pseudocode does?

```
service_resource = service myservice do
  # somehow don't execute this right now, but wait for
  # signal from resource1 or resource2
  action :stop
end

resource1 do
  make sure service_resource executed first
  only_if { condition1 }
end

resource2 do
  make sure service_resource executed first
  only_if { condition2 }
end
```

If there was some "notifies :before" mechanism in Chef (instead of e.g. "notifies :immediately"), I could use this, but I haven't found anything of the sort. Any ideas?

EDIT:

After thinking about this some more, another way of doing it, still not perfect but better, would be by taking advantage of the compile phase of Chef by defining a single attribute that's overwritten. That way at least we don't have to keep all conditions in one place.

```
# in an "attributes" file:
default["stop_service"] = false

# in some recipe:
service myservice do
  action :stop
  only_if { node["stop_service"] }
end

# ... later, or in some other recipe file
condition1 = ... # true/false
if condition1
  # I think this executes before the only_if of the "service" resource
  override["stop_service"] = true
end

resource1 do
  only_if { condition1 }
end
```

Comment: Most services on UNIXlike operating systems can have their configuration (or even code, as long as the local package manager replaces files by creating new inodes rather than rewriting existing inodes to have new content) updated while live, which is why this isn't a common problem -- most of the time, a service doesn't need to be stopped before reconfiguration or upgrade takes place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In the end maybe that's what I'll rely on, but what I wrote is actually a simplification: we have a bunch of services, and I'm not sure all of them can have their config changed while running. I think at least one of them reloads its config automatically, so it could reload while only partial changes have been applied. Also for some recipes we append / replace in existing files, so in these cases we're not using new inodes (if I understood correctly what you meant).

Comment: Depends on exactly how the append/replace functionality works -- safe implementations (when the data being appended is more than fits in one syscall, or when any in-place edits are needed) work by writing a temporary file in the same directory and renaming it over the destination. But yes, makes sense that you'd want to do a restart (or a SIGSTOP and SIGCONT, if supported) around config changes if you want those changes to be atomic, multiple files are modified, and automatic reload behavior is implemented.

Comment: Actually I didn't realize it but you're right. Most of the time we're using "sed -i" ("inplace", which, I just read, does what you describe). In some other cases we use Chef::Util:FileEdit, which doesn't do exactly what you described but keeps a backup of the old file, so the old inode is still untouched (I think).

Answer (score 3):

What I would do:

Stage the configuration in a "staging" place, if this change, notifies stop, copy files, start the service.

Something along the line:

```
service "my_service" do 
  action :nothing
end

template "/staging/conf1" do
  [... usual attributes ...]
  notifies :stop,"service[my_service]",:immediately
end

template "/staging/conf2" do
  [... usual attributes ...]
  notifies :stop,"service[my_service]",:immediately
end

remote_file "/opt/my_service/etc/conf1" do
  source "/staging/conf1"
  notifies :start,"service[my_service]" # delayed here to allow all conf files to be updated.
end

remote_file "/opt/my_service/etc/conf2" do
  source "/staging/conf2"
  notifies :start,"service[my_service]" # delayed here to allow all conf files to be updated.
end
```

My personnal taste goes to loop over files/template definition hash for this kind of option with the same resources like:

```
node['my_namespace']['conf_files']['conf1'] = "template1"
node['my_namespace']['conf_files']['conf2'] = "template2"
```

and then looping over with

```
node['my_namespace']['conf_files'].each do |cfgfile,tmplname|
  template "/staging/#{cfgfile}" do
     source tmplname
     notifies :stop,"service[my_service]",:immediately
  end

  remote_file "/opt/my_service/etc/#{cfgfile}" do
    source "/staging/#{cfgfile}"
    notifies :start,"service[my_service]"
  end
end
```

For more complex use cases you may use a hash instead of a single value too

If there's more than 2 resources involved (executing specific commands for the conf file to validate it before replacing the actual one, etc.) a definition could fit.

Another could be to do all the staging work in the `load_current_resource` of a LWRP but I may be going too far for the described use case.

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai. It could work for some types of resources, I think, but it really affects the structure of the recipes. I'm trying to avoid such big changes and keep recipes as "natural" as possible, which is why I'm looking for something like "notifies :before" (which would require some magic with the "Chef Resource Queue"... but if it's not in the framework, there's not much to be done).

Comment: @fsdj Well the case has been discussed [Here](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2421) with some trials about it.Comments on the PR linked in the ticket tell the why it is not in chef actually.

Comment: Oh wow that's exactly what I meant. So yeah, I guess it's really _not_ doable in Chef for the moment ("without a large refactor", as the PR says). A "depends" between resources would have been even better (to avoid running the previous step multiple times, like someone mentioned). Thanks a lot, that'll avoid further useless digging.